# Linq left joining with non trivial condition

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, left-join, on-clause

This is fine, it produces a left join

```
var q =
    from c in categories
    join p in products 
    on c equals p.Category into ps
    from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Category = c, ProductName = p == null ? "(No products)" : p.ProductName };
```

But what about if I wanted to do something like this:

```
...
on p.date between c.startdate and c.enddate
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var q =
    from c in categories
    join p in products 
    on c equals p.Category into ps
    from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where p.date >= c.startdate && p.date <= c.enddate
    select new { Category = c, ProductName = p == null ? "(No products)" : p.ProductName };
```

Comment: Except I'm not interested in the original on clause. I replaced it with on 1 equals 1. Won't that be terribly burdensome though?